# Github PR from feature/branch to Develop and PR from develop to Master branch with Squash and Merge

Tags: git, github, pull-request

We have branches like

```
feature/branch-->develop-->master
```

Below are the step I followed

```
1. Created a `feature/branch` from the origin which is a `develop` branch 
2. Committed on `feature/branch` and `git rebase origin/develop` and push it to remote `feature/branch`
3. Raised a PR from `feature/branch` to `develop` branch 
4. Performed `Squash and Merge` above step 3
5. Raised a PR from `develop` branch to `master` branch 
6. Performed `Squash and Merge` above step 5
```

**Issue:**  I see only one commit and only changes to my files in step 3, BUT when I raise a  PR from `develop --> master` branch it shows previous commits instead of only my commits

How do I resolve such issues and avoid having such in every Pull request? Whats steps need to be taken so that everyone's feature/branch 's PR is not having such issues

Currently temporary to avoid such issues, we are following `merge` PR for every Pull Request. But I want to avoid it to have a clean commit history and not have too many commit history

Comment: Basically you have conflicting desires so there is no solution. Squash and merge is not a merge; it is a rebase (plus a squash). So the history is eradicated and you get the "previous commits" as you describe. That is one reason for doing real merge on pull requests. Personally, I _like_ the "train track sidings" history that that generates.

Comment: I think you _might_ be able to solve the problem by doing the merge manually (locally) rather than relying on GitHub. In other words, develop-to-master would just be a merge, not a pull request. What we do is merge master to develop and then develop to master. But we also don't squash.

Comment: too much PR. As @matt said, develop-to-master would just be a merge. Why a PR from develop to master is required?

Comment: Trying to understand, Do you mean git merge from develop to master ?.If that's the case how will we know whether previous commits or only latest commits are merging into Master from Develop

Comment: It seems (forgive my saying so) like you don't have a good mental image of what a merge _is_. Only two commits are involved in an ordinary merge: the commits named by the branches (what most people think of as the "latest" commit on the branch). Exactly what git does when asked to merge depends upon where the ancestry of those two commits diverged. Git effectively replays both lines of development from that point simultaneously and makes a new commit out of that.